# Системное приложение Камера. Сохранение фото без потери качества

Tags: android, файлы, изображения

Использую системное приложение камера. В приведенном ниже коде все работает, фото сохраняется, но его качество кардинально отличается от оригинала.Как получить доступ к полноценному сделанному фото, как сохранить оригинальный снимок?

Вызов камеры:

```
Intent intentPhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intentPhoto, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);
```

onActivityResult:

```
case REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                im_photo.setImageBitmap(thumbnailBitmap);
                try {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPhoto/";
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    File mFile = new File(path, "IMG_"+ time + ".jpeg");
                    File file = new File(path);
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.mkdirs();
                    }
                    mFile.createNewFile();
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                    thumbnailBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }
```

Comment: А оригинал что в данном случае?